# PHP - Access/modify an array without making it Global or a function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, global-variables

I have an associative array that gets populated from a few different sources - with some content drawn from a database.

I need the ability to access this array from within a few different functions.

I don't want to make the array global, for best practice reasons. I don't want to contain the array within a function, because I would be calling that function in a loop, causing the array to unnecessarily re-populate on each call (I did some tests and this would affect performance too much).

I could populate the array once and pass it through as a parameter into each function that required it, but due to some legacy code elsewhere, this would be a nightmare to set up.

Do I have any other option than setting the array as a global? Could I approach this in a different way? I haven't pasted any code snippets as I don't think they'd help in this situation!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `pass-by-reference`.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes! Thank you, that is exactly what will solve the problem!